# constantize incorrectly returning top-level class instead of NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-2.1

We recently upgraded our Rails 3.2.16 application to Ruby 2.1.0. I started seeing routing errors on some of our legacy routes, the ones that just rely on pattern matching alone:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

I discovered that we had a controller with an action that matched the "controller name" of another top-level controller. For example:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
end

class BarsController < ApplicationController
  def foos
  end
end
```

Rails is trying to route `/bars/foos/19.json` to `FoosController#19` instead of `BarsController#foos` with an `:id` parameter of 19.

Ultimately, I traced it to `ActiveSupport::Inflector.constantize`, and the behavior is easy to reproduce:

```
001:0> class Foo; end
nil
002:0> class Bar; end
nil
003:0> Bar::Foo.name
(irb):3: warning: toplevel constant Foo referenced by Bar::Foo
"Foo"
```

Isn't this wrong? It should raise a `NameError` because `Bar::Foo` is not defined. This is currently breaking our routing, but I imagine it could break a lot of other places too.

---

**Update 2014-Mar-18**: I was able to reproduce this same behavior in irb Ruby 1.9.3 (without Rails), so it's not a problem with `constantize`, or else it's a problem with how `constantize` works in Ruby 2.1.0.

The actual class names are `PduFirmwareUpgradeController` (which has the `#pdus` action) and `PdusController`. I'm not sure what I can do other than rename the action to something unique.

Comment: are there any namespaces involved? can you please replace the names with the real ones you use? when you define a class, you ultimately define a constant on `Object`, that's why you can call `(Object::)Bar::Foo`, i don't think that this is a root of the error.

Comment: @phoet I'm sorry, I just now saw your reply and updated the question. The bounty is ending in 7 hours, but I'll reopen it if you think you can help.